# How to Access WCF Service Behind NAT

Tags: c#, wcf, network-programming

Here is my situation :

- I have a WCF with TCP Binding Service  behind NAT and I am not able
  to reach it.
- I can reach my service using BasicHttpBinding and Raw TCP Sockets.
- At server side port forwarding is done.

What may cause this ?

My Network Topology: [Picture Link](http://i61.tinypic.com/fp2e0n.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some firewall rules. The router with take care of the address translation.

Comment: Can you connect via net tcp from a client on the same network as the server? I would test this first to remove firewall/port forward/etc problems from the equation.

Comment: Did you already thought about CORS? You are using different ip addresses. When I read the comments on rodolk answer it has to be a CORS problem. Do you also receive 'CONNECTION REFUSED' errors or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not experienced with WCF and nettcpbinding but this could help.

Theoretically it is not possible because your service has a local IP address, corresponding to the LAN where it is attached, and not a public IP address. So it could not be reached from the Internet, outside the NAT. However, almost all NAT devices, maybe your router/Access Point, have a feature for "Port Forwarding". This feature allows you to define that all packets addressed to a specific port are forwarded to a specific machine within you LAN, with a private IP address.

This could be a solution for you if you can overcome two hinders:

1-I don't know how the node in the Internet will send a message to the callback server. If it uses the IP address from which it received the request, there is not problem. If it receives a callback-IP address, then you have to figure out how to find out the public IP address of you NAT (maybe router/Access Point) and send out that IP address.

2-Your service behind a NAT needs to open a client port, or ephemeral port, to communicate with the service outside the NAT. If the second sends the message to the client port from which it received the message, you have to find a way to determine the client port you want to open (must be the same you configured in port forwarding). Will it listen in port 808 by default?

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can make raw TCP/IP connection between machine behind NAT and client.So it seems that there is no problem about port opening. But some how  can not connect wcf service

Comment: And I can make connection using BasicHttpBinding.But can not with Net Tcp

Comment: Regarding first comment, where is the said client? Outside NAT?. Second comment: You need to determine which is the (receiving) port used by net TCP service? Is it always the same?

Comment: 1-What exact exception message are you getting in the WCF client? Let's check if it is TCP-layer or Application-layer. 2-Can you use Wireshark in the client host?

Comment: Client get Error: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. 
This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. 
Local socket timeout was '00:09:59.9939913'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: I got this exception very quickly...just in milliseconds

Comment: I can not usefull information at client side . Just see "TCP 60 irdmi > 52527 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=44 Win=65536 Len=0" packets

Comment: OK, it TCP-layer. Probably the NAT device is not forwarding. Can you see to which port the client is sending? Surely it is not the port that you configued for Port Forwarding or it is not the port where the server is listening.

Comment: At Client
Source port : 52527
DestinationPort :irdmi (8000)

[ service url is net.tcp://y.y.y.y:8000/Service" form ]

Comment: At Server : At Server
Source port : irdmi (8000)
DestinationPort : 52527

Comment: It seems that messages come to server. But it refuses. It does not refuse in Basic Http Bindings

Comment: That's a progress. The client host is reaching the services host through the NAT device. Looking at the RST message from service, the TCP connection was established and then closed (ACK=44, so client already send some data). Now it's a problem of understanding why app server is refusing the request to that service. Maybe a permission problem or the service URI used is not correct.

Comment: Have you tried with a client in the same LAN? I bet you're going to have the same issue.

Comment: No. I tried and it works on same machine. Actually with Basic HTTP Binding works for also Remote Server. But failed at TCP Binding

Comment: Did you have any progress? Let me know to my personal e-mail so that we don't make this thread so long (and I'll continue helping): rodolk@yahoo.com

Comment: No progress unfortunately. So I decide to make communication via TCP. Here is my mail also lesser.hippias@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Check with URI "net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8000", this will ensure that the service will accept connection from any inbound IP address. At server side, the IP address mentioned in the URI & address from which the connection is accepted differs so the server is dropping the connection.